# bounding box around selected objects in obj model in three.js

Tags: three.js

on selecting a particular item in an imported `.obj` model in `three.js` editor, the bounding box appears around the entire world instead of appearing on the selected object.

I have used `THREE.BoundingBoxHelper()` to make the bounding box, and passed the picked object to it. I also call the update function on the bounding Box.

Is there a way to make the bounding box appear only around the selected item in the `3D world`?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at 100% but as far as I know, once you import in .obj the whole import became a single object (just like using json format) - in your case the whole 3d world; so, to reply to your question, the answer is NO. There are other ways anyway to do it:
1. import the scene and the object you are interested separately, so you can compute the boundingBox
2. use different way to import, like Collada; this post can be helpful: [ThreeJs and Blender (using colladaLoader): first contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224940/threejs-and-blender-using-colladaloader-first-contact/23245184#23245184)